# Nuxt3 env vars are empty in production when injected with Docker

Tags: docker, vue.js, environment-variables, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I was using environment variables with a PaaS (render.com) and it worked as expected. I decided to self host my sebsite and use Docker instead, but now, my variables are empty. Here is what I did:

*  nuxt.config.ts*

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    runtimeConfig: {
      public: {
        uris: {
          backHost: process.env.NUXT_BACK_HOST_URL
        }
      }
    }
})
```

*env file*

```
NUXT_BACK_HOST_URL=https://example.com
```

In docker-compose.yml file, for the nuxt service, I inject this env file using `env_file` attribute. I can confirm this step works, because running a `printenv` command directly on my running container, I get:

```
$ docker exec -it nuxt_service printenv
> NUXT_BACK_HOST_URL=https://example.com
  NODE_ENV=production
  // some other variables
```

This shows my runtime environment variables are well defined in my container.  In the nuxt code, I'm accessing them this way:

```
const { uris } = useRuntimeConfig().public;
const backUri = uris.backHost // empty in production!!!
```

#### Random notes

- This works in local development, with `.env` file being injected by the vite server.
- As I said, the exact same nuxt code and env was working when using a PaaS hosting service
- I'm using my website in SSR (not in SPA mode), except in a single page, so this is not the issue
- I build the nuxt project in a Dockerfile using `npm run build` (but I guess it's unrelated as I'm talking about runtime vars)

Comment: variable should not be named NUXT_PUBLIC_URIS_BACK_HOST_URL?